# Import font in Hummus Recipe

Tags: pdf, fonts

I am developing a project on node and would like to know how to import a source such as a .ttf

```
const HummusRecipe = require('hummus-recipe');
const pdfDoc = new HummusRecipe('input.pdf', 'output.pdf');
pdfDoc
    // edit 1st page
    .editPage(1)
    .text('Add some texts to an existing pdf file', 150, 300)
    .rectangle(20, 20, 40, 100)
    .comment('Add 1st comment annotaion', 200, 300)
    .image('/path/to/image.jpg', 20, 100, {width: 300, keepAspectRatio: true})
    .endPage()
    // edit 2nd page
    .editPage(2)
    .comment('Add 2nd comment annotaion', 200, 100)
    .endPage()
    // end and save
    .endPDF();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing on Mac rather than relative path using `'./'` notation straight path works `'path/to/font'`

```
const pdfDoc = new HummusRecipe(input, output);
pdfDoc.registerFont('My Font', 'path/to/font/file.ttf');
```

And then use this way.

```
pdfDoc
  // edit 1st page
  .editPage(1)
  .text(name, 'center', 219, {
    color: '#e5ae0b',
    fontSize: 30,
    font: 'My Font',
    align: 'center center',
    opacity: 0.8
  })
  .text(course, 240, 288)
  .endPage()
  // end and save
  .endPDF();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do either

```js
const pdfDoc = new HummusRecipe(input, output, {
  fontSrcPath: './path/to/font/folder',
}
```

Or

```js
const pdfDoc = new HummusRecipe(input, output)
pdfDoc.registerFont('My Font', './path/to/font/file.ttf')
```

See https://github.com/chunyenHuang/hummusRecipe/blob/master/tests/font.js